# "pip install geopy" = done, but not found in visual studio code :(

Tags: python, installation, pip

Can someone help me please.
I am a beginner in Python.
On my mac I have installed 'geopy' via the terminal.
But in Visual Studio Code, I get :

File "/Users/petermadou/Documents/mijn python projects/nieuw project/nieuw.py", line 1, in 
import geopy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'

Probably something stupid...

what gives ?

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 0):

It seems the GeoPy module did not install.

Start Python ($ Python3) through your terminal and type
`help('modules')`

This should print all modules installed. If you do not see GeoPy try pip installing the module again.

I do recommend trying out the [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) distribution which helps with package management. [Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) has functionality that allows you to use Anaconda.